# Can't str_replace one character with PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace the `’` e.g. `KPI’s` with "" in PHP. I get it out of an array.

```
echo "before:".$columnarray[$i]."<br/>";
$columnarray[$i] = str_replace("&#x2018;", "", $columnarray[$i]);
echo "after:".$columnarray[$i]."<br/>";
```

I tried out 12 different special characters out of this homepage http://sonderzeichentabelle.de/ ... but nothing works.

What do I make wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does your string value contain an encoded entity, or an actual literal `’`?  `str_replace()` is perfectly capable of operating on the literal value.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($columnarray[$i]));` to know what you're *actually* getting.

Comment: Also see at source code of result

Comment: If it's not being replaced, that means your string does not contain "&#x2018;".

Comment: vardump produces string(254)

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
$columnarray[$i] = str_replace("&#x2018;", "", $columnarray[$i]);
```

to

```
$columnarray[$i] = str_replace("'", "", $columnarray[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `str_replace` is looking for the literal `&#x2018;` and not the character that it represents which is why it isn't being replaced.  You need to convert it to the character and use that.  I believe that you want to use [`chr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)  You can find out exactly which code that the character is by using [`ord()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

You will need to use ord() to determine what the code is.  You can also use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) as your character isn't an Ascii code.

```
$character = html_entity_decode('&#x2018;', ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
str_replace($character, "", $columnarray[$i]);
```

To find the correct code dump `html_entity_decode($columnarray[$i])` and see what the code is and replace in the above code.

Comment: Sounds good but I dont know what I should do now. Isn't there a special character code which I can use for str_replace function to replace ’ ?

Comment: Hm it isn't working ... I added a picture above in my post. There you see the ouput

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophe is one of the [biggest pains of digital typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Computing), basically for this reason. There are two common variants (typographic = curly, typewriter = straight) which you managed to use both of in your question, and two of each of those variants (left and right), as well as at least three similar looking characters that are often misused in the place of the apostrophe (prime, okina, grave). Read more on this on wikipedia or countless typophile sites.

The easiest solution is to take advantage of the ability to pass `str_replace` an array of values to find:

```
$apostrophes = array(
    "curly-left" => "‘",
    "curly-right" => "’",
    "straight-left" => "'",
    "straight-right" => "'",
    "prime" => "′",
    "okina" => "ʻ",
    "grave" => "`"
    );

$columnarray[$i] = str_replace($apostrophes, "", $columnarray[$i]);
```

Comment: Seems good! But still not works. I think its something with Notepad++ or ... mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");  or I dont know ...